# Is it possible anyhow to load resources to an iOS app after it is installed on device?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, afnetworking-2

I want to reduce the size of the app to its minimum level. So what all resources i can load from remote after installation? I know I can download images from remote. But can I download libraries or pods from remote after installation? I know we need those files to generate ipa files. Is there any way to setup app with minimum required code, and "load" rest of the code from remote, and is it even possible?

On a different note, I think there should be a framework which checks for existing libraries (like AF Networking) on device, and if it is not there, then downloads it, and all the apps which need it use it. This will help reduce the size of apps considerably.

Comment: I wonder why there's a thing called "dll hell".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For assets (images, movies, sounds, etc...) absolutely.

For executable code (libraries, frameworks and pods) absolutely not.

That would directly contradict one of the rules that Apple has in place on apps on the App Store.

Any executable code has to be bundled and submitted to the App Store for approval.

Apple's iOS developer guidelines state:

> 3.3.2 — An Application may not itself install or launch other executable code by any means, including without limitation through the use of a plug-in architecture, calling other frameworks, other APIs or otherwise. No interpreted code may be downloaded or used in an Application except for code that is interpreted and run by Apple’s Documented APIs and built-in interpreter(s).